# Firestore integration with Django

Tags: django, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, web-applications, pyrebase

I have a Firebase Firestore database connected to a Flutter mobile application. I want to build a web application to manage the users' data and handle new users. I have decided to use Django for my web application, but I have two questions if anyone can help.

First, is it actually reliable to use Django as the framework for this purpose?
Second, I was trying to make a connection between Django and my existing DB to just try to call some values but I was getting this error:

> google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application.

Here is the code I am using for the connection

```
db = firestore.Client()

config={
    "apiKey": "******************",
    "authDomain": "*******.firebaseapp.com",
    "projectId": "*******",
    "storageBucket": "*******.appspot.com",
    "messagingSenderId": "*******",
    "appId": "******************",
    "databaseURL": "https://***********.firebaseio.com",
}    
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
auth = firebase.auth()
database = firebase.database()

def index(request):
   doc = db.collection('test').document('test1').stream()
   weight= doc['weight']
   
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        "weight":weight,
    })
```

Comment: Where does your `firestore` object come from? That doesn't exist in [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase), so most likely it comes from another SDK, and you'll need to initialize that. For example, as shown here for the Python Admin SDK in the documentation on [setting up Firebase on your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#python_1)

Comment: Read this article https://www.section.io/engineering-education/integrating-firebase-database-in-django/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) with client-side configuration data. But Pyrebase doesn't have any built-in support for Firestore, so most likely you'e importing that from elsewhere. If your `firestore` comes from the Admin SDK that Firebase itself supports for use in Python code, you'll need to initialize that SDK too, as shown here in the documentation on [setting up Firebase on your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#python_1)

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. I tried to follow the process from the documentation but I still got the same error. here is how I initiated the connection and please let me know if I did something wrong ..... cred = credentials.Certificate("./serviceAccountKey.json")   
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

Comment: The issue was solved by adding this line to the file setting.py os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="./serviceAccountKey.json"